# Pandas vectorized string comparison operations with 2 columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, vectorization

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Route': pd.Categorical(["ChicagoVenice", "MiamiAtlanta", "BirminghamLondon", "BostonRome"]),
    'City1': pd.Categorical(["Venice", "Miami", "London", "Boston"]),
    })
```

```
              Route   City1
0     ChicagoVenice  Venice
1      MiamiAtlanta   Miami
2  BirminghamLondon  London
3        BostonRome  Boston
```

I would like to calculate another column City2 that compares Route with City1 and extracts the remaining string.

```
              Route   City1       City2
0     ChicagoVenice  Venice     Chicago
1      MiamiAtlanta   Miami     Atlanta
2  BirminghamLondon  London  Birmingham
3        BostonRome  Boston        Rome
```

I thought about using string.split() with numpy.vectorize(), but I couldn't figure out how to apply this properly to 2 columns.

```py
def get_city2(route, city1):
    route_split = route.split(city1)
    city2 = ''.join(route_split).split()[0]
    return city2

df['City2'] = np.vectorize(get_city2)(df['Route'], df['City1'])[1]
```

My result is not exactly what I want :-(

```
              Route   City1    City2
0     ChicagoVenice  Venice  Atlanta
1      MiamiAtlanta   Miami  Atlanta
2  BirminghamLondon  London  Atlanta
3        BostonRome  Boston  Atlanta
```

Has anyone an idea how to solve this without looping? I would favor a neat vectorized solution if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
df['City2']=df.apply(lambda x : x.Route.replace(x.City1,''),axis=1)
```

Comment: That's a very nice solution, short and efficient. I like it! I guess the np.vectorized() option might be more appropriate when there are more complicated tasks to fulfill...

Answer (score 1):

I got it myself, the functions is actually all fine, there was just a little mistake in the np.vectorize assignment.

Now it's working like a charm. :-)

```py
df['City2'] = np.vectorize(get_city2)(df['Route'], df['City1'])
```

Cheers!